# Remove DetailHeader Band when Detail Field Values is NULL

Tags: ireport

I'm printing the Detail Header on Every Page so i would like to hide the Detail header band when there is **no data** available in the detail band .

How do I implement this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Right-click the desired band and at the right side you will see the **Print When Expression**
There you can enter any condition you want. Say for example:

```
$F{my_primary_key}!=null
```

Here the band will always print when a row is returned.

**2)** You can also consider right-clicking **your report name in the report inspector** (top node) --->Properties-->**When No Data**---> you have 04 options:

- All sections, no detail
- Blank page
- No Data Section
- No pages.